# FBSDKShareDialog doesn't post my content

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Facebook ios SDK v.4.9.1. With 4.8.0 was the same.

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentTitle = title;
content.contentURL = url;
content.contentDescription = description;
content.imageURL = imageUrl;

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self.presentingViewController withContent:content delegate:self];
```

- When user is logged into Facebook in System Settings but facebook app isn't installed, appears shareSheet with blank title, image and description.
- When user is logged into Facebook in System Settings and facebook app is installed, opens facebook app with sharing dialog, where post have strange title, image and description, automatically pulled from link. (not from content)

In both situations published post have automatically pulled title, image and description.

- When user isn't logged into Facebook in System Settings, or i set

  dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser;

opens post in browser with correct content, and publishes correctly too.

**It isn't link to App Store, just on site.**
Behavior is identical on iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Comment: Make sure you required "publish_actions" permission within your current access token check this [URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions) for more information